# How do I set up my Playstation 1 emulator files?

Tags: emulation, ps1

I recently got a Raspberry Pi 3 and I installed Retropie on it using my Linux system. I found out that it can emulate Playstation 1 games so I downloaded all three Crash Bandicoot games. When I extracted the .rar files I noticed that they didn't extract to .iso files. It made a folder for every one of them. The first two games have a .bin.ecm file and a .cue file and the third game has a .bin file and a .cue file. I haven't really seen anything like this with emulation and I am wondering how I would manage these files. Do I have to convert anything? Why are the files different? Also, do I put all the individual files into the rom directory or do I put each folder into the directory?

Note: I thought that it might be worth mentioning that for anyone who isn't familiar with Retropie the way that you add games to the system is use a fat32 USB drive and put a folder called retropie in it. You plug it into the Raspberry Pi and the Pi creates directories for all the different rom types. You can then put the USB stick back into the PC and put the extracted roms into the matching directories on the USB drive. When you plug it into the Ras Pi again it will copy any new roms from the USB drive to the right rom directories in the system.

Comment: .bin files are a completely common extension for disk roms and .cue is just extra information about the disk. Not sure about .ecm, but I'm sure that's also extra information about the disk, and even if it's not, by rights, .bin should work on its own without the extra files (although I would keep them just in case). I would also recommend transfering the roms using [SFTP or Samba-Shares](https://github.com/retropie/retropie-setup/wiki/Transferring-Roms), just because you can also delete old roms with it and you have full access to the internal memory of your SD card.

Comment: Flagged as off-topic because they specifically say that they downloaded the ROMs.

Comment: @Chaosblessed Voting to leave this question open. This seems to be on-topic as per the [meta] post, [What's the official stance on console emulation?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/102/4797) Doesn't matter how OP obtained said ROMs.

Comment: @galacticninja I have flagged questions in the past that were closed as off-topic *specifically because the askers mentioned that they downloaded the ROMs.*

Comment: Emulation itself is legal and allowed here, but the core thrust of this question seems to be how to handle pirated games to work with the emulator.  I tried to edit the question to remove mention of the files, but found I couldn't without invalidating the question entirely.  Caden, I'd recommend attempting to edit this to focus on emulation functionality with the Retropie, if possible to do so without invalidating the existing answer.

Answer (score 3):

[.ecm](https://www.lifewire.com/ecm-file-2620956) is a file extension often used in emulation to save a bit of space. 
You need a tool to convert it back to a usable format. Something like [ECM tools](https://www.emuparadise.me/Sony_Playstation_ISOs/ecm_tools/36839)